# Ошибка AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'endswith' при поиске файлов с расширением в python 3

Tags: python-3.x

```
from os import*

workdir = ''

def chooseWorkdir():
    global workdir
    workdir = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory()

def filter():
    filename = listdir(workdir)
    extension = '.png'
    filename.endswith(extension)
```

Ошибка:

`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'endswith'`

подскажите что делать пожалуйста

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: `for filename in listdir(workdir): ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Во-первых почти не понятно для чего код и что вы хотите получить.* Но вроде для фильтрации файлов в директории по паттерну. Если что то функция `listdir()` возвращает **СПИСОК** всех папок и файлов в директории.

Вот код для удаления не подходящих элементов и файлов.

```
all_dirs_and_files = os.listdir(workdir)
norm_files = []
ext = '.png'
for el in all_dirs_and_files:
    if os.path.isfile(el) and el.endswith(ext): # Проверка файл ли это и формат файла
        norm_files.append(el)
```

`norm_files` - все **файлы** с форматом `png`

### Почему ошибка:

Пишет что у `filename` нет атрибута `endswith`. Но ведь `listdir()` возвращает список, а не строку, а у списка нет ни метода, ни атрибута `endswith()`. Он есть только у строк.